# How to delete whiskers from a box plot graphic built with ggplot()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to remove the whiskers from a boxplot graphic created with ggplot() package. The boxplot is done for plotting Mean and Standard error using a custom function `MinMeanSEMMax`. I really appreciate your help!
Here the script that I used:

```
MinMeanSEMMax <- function(x) {
  v <- c(min(x), mean(x) - sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), mean(x), mean(x) + sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), max(x))
  names(v) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  v
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill=factor(am))) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=MinMeanSEMMax, geom="boxplot", colour="black") + 
  ggtitle("mtcars boxplot") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="OrRd")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just redefine your function so that `ymin = lower` and `ymax = upper`:

```
MinMeanSEMMax <- function(x) {
  v <- c(mean(x) - sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), mean(x) - sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), mean(x),
         mean(x) + sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)), mean(x) + sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
  names(v) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  v
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill=factor(am))) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=MinMeanSEMMax, geom="boxplot", colour="black") + 
  ggtitle("mtcars boxplot") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="OrRd")
```

[image]